# Integration using identity

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a problem in my textbook that involves integrating without the use of techniques (no parts, u-sub...). I have to use what I know about the integrand to break it down, simplify it into simpler terms.
I need integrate 1/(4 + x^2)

My attempt: I realized that this looks similar to arctan in form. I know I should have arctan in my equation. I tried arctan(x/2) and I got 1/(1+(x^2)/4)). Is this simplification right?

I look at the answer and it is (arctan(x/2))/2. I try to find the derivative of this and I use quotient rule and get (1/1+x^2 *2)/2 =2/(1/4 +(x^2)/4). I was not able to get the original integral. Is their some mistake in my simplification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $\int\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2}=\frac{1}{a} tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{a})+c$